# Given $r$ distinct objects,in how many ways we can distribute them in $n$ buckets,assuming the objects contained in a bucket have a permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

Given $r$ distinct objects,in how many ways we can distribute them in $n$ buckets,assuming the objects contained in a bucket  have a permutation?

I think the answer is :
$$\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+...+k_{n}=r}^{ }\binom{r}{k_{1}}\binom{r-k_{1}}{k_{2}}\cdot\cdot\cdot\binom{r-k_{1}-...-k_{n-1}}{k_{n}}k_{1}!k_{2}!\cdot\cdot\cdot k_{n}!$$$$=r!\sum_{k_{1}+k_{2}+...+k_{n}+=r}^{ }=r!\binom{r+n-1}{r}$$

First we choose $k_1$ objects from $r$ objects and then $k_2$ from the remaining...,also for the objects contained in each bucket there are $k_i$ objects for $1\le i\le n$,summing all over possible such $k_i$'s gives the answer,also the last binomial coefficient comes from the nonnegative integral solutions to the equation $k_{1}+k_{2}+...+k_{n}+=r$

But I'm not sure if the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Nice job!
If the buckets are indistinguishable, then no. You have to divide by $n!$ because you are giving the buckets an order when you do $r!$ so the answer would be $\frac{r!}{n!}\binom{r+n-1}{r}$ Notice that if you don't allow empty buckets, this numbers are the famous [Lah numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number) And your formula is very similar, just with the difference that there you do not allow empty buckets.

If you can permute the buckets (they are distinguishable), then yes! You are correct.

Comment: @45465 No, notice that this order of the buckets is imposed with the $r!$ so your previous answer was correct. $r!\binom{r+n-1}{r}$ because you are placing a linear order over ALL elements, so when you distribute them, the buckets end up having a linear order :)

Comment: Notice that you have a linear order inside the buckets, so you are missing for example: $|\, |\, 21$

Comment: If i counted them correctly, you should get 12 by the formula and by adding the $3$ configurations.

Comment: Also I do not understand what "pairwise disjoint" means in this context. I still believe you are fine from the beginning. I was just noticing the two possibilities of distinguishable and non distinguishable blocks.

Comment: @45465 Indeed! Again, nice job.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you got it right. You can also think of it the other way. You can think of the $r$ distinct objects as $r$ indistinguishable balls, with numeric stickers $1,2,\cdots,r$, attached on them. First take off the stickers and then distribute the $r$ indistinguishable balls into the $n$ boxes, which can be done in $\binom{r+n-1}{r}$ ways, then attach the $r$ stickers on the balls in any $r!$ possible ways, giving you $r!\binom{r+n-1}{r}$ possible arrangements.